# How to remove/disable Firefox Developer Tools?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

How remove the "Firefox Developer Tools" from Firefox 28.0? 
Is there a way or script or option in `about:config` to remove them permanently?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't remove them, because they are integrated into Firefox. Though various tools have a corresponding preference in [`about:config`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/about:config) to enable/disable them.

Just search for `devtools.*.enabled` there and set all of the appearing options to `false`.

See also the [thread about this](https://support.mozilla.org/de/questions/977129) in the support.mozilla.org forum.

*Note: As long as the DevTools are not opened they don't use any memory.*

Comment: This does not work on my Linux box, Firefox 43 and 38. I disabled everything, but F12 and Ctrl-Shift-I still showed me the devtools console.

Comment: As I said, you *cannot* disable the devtools completely via those settings, though as long as you don't open them, they also don't do anything besides allocating some shortcuts to open them.

Comment: I can't dissable Ctrl+shift+c, it always opens Dom inspector. I need this shortcut in another app.

Comment: Changing and disabling the Ctrl+Shift+C shortcut is described in http://stackoverflow.com/a/36007668/432681.

Answer (score 1):

The above doesn't work on Linux. Inspectors and all still popup.

[edit]. There isn't a way to disable this inspector, but with this extension you can disable shortcuts:
Keybinder: 
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/keybinder/
(Above is to replace Customizable Shortcuts by Tim Taubert, which is no longer developed/removed)

Config -> Shortcut mapping -> change > (find shortcut, disable).

Comment: None of that's going to stop right-click > inspect element.

Comment: Why downvote? Same as in accepted answer, you cannot disable devtools. This solution at least allows you to minimize it's visibility.
Please explain justification for downvote.